# Authorization for multiple Asp.net web applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-authorization

we have 2 asp.net applications. Each get authorized based on Active Directory Group members.

Now the client is looking for AUTHORIZATION for these two asp.net web applications. What would be the best way to do so and the steps to achieve this.

Comment: Did you check the authorization pages in the docs? You can use groups for role based authorization

Comment: I don't get it clearly, does client want authorize 2 application with same credential? Edit: Could this be answer for your problem https://ricardodsanchez.com/2013/05/24/how-to-use-active-directory-groups-to-restrict-access-to-controller-actions-in-asp-net-mvc-and-make-your-application-even-more-secure/

Comment: @UmutGür  yes they want to authorize with the same credentials. But not in MVC but in asp.net web applications

Answer (score 1):

You can use OWIN for Authentication and Authorization in ASP .NET WEB FORMS

Check this for OWIN setup for Web Forms https://www.codeproject.com/tips/849113/four-easy-steps-to-set-up-owin-for-form-authentica

Then you can create a method attribute for AD Groups like [AuthorizeForAD]

There is a article about that for MVC, but don't worry you can use this attribute for Web Forms too. https://ricardodsanchez.com/2013/05/24/how-to-use-active-directory-groups-to-restrict-access-to-controller-actions-in-asp-net-mvc-and-make-your-application-even-more-secure/

If you don't know about attributes you can check this article for authentication with attributes. http://derans.blogspot.com/2011/03/simplify-authorization-with-attribute.html

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks much i will have this verifed and then i would give green tick